# How to implement a before script only in specific branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project that build a zip file of the project, the stage look like that :

```
create-artefact:
  image: someurl/phpscl-dev:0.7.1
  stage: archive
  tags:
    - rsc
    - shared
    - docker
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - rm -rf bin
    - composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
    - ant -buildfile build.xml -Dversion=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} -DcomponentName=${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}-${CI_PROJECT_NAME} -DbuildDir=${BUILD_DIR} archive
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ${BUILD_DIR}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}-${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.zip
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - develop
```

What I would like to do the following action before anything :

- If the branch is develop do this
- If the branch is master do that

Is it possible ? How could I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just create to different steps, and add :

```
 only:
    refs:
      - master
```

or

```
 only:
    refs:
      - develop
```

to them.

Comment: Can I use the same name 'create-artefact' for both ?

Comment: It’ll be confusing but you can try it